# Image not fitting in jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to fit mo website logo image inside a jumbotron. But somehow it just does not fits there. I have attached the output as an image. Here is the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/emmF5.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="The DreamShream Quiz has the best and most updated quiz questions on various categories. Visit now!" />
<meta name="keywords" content="general knowledge, quiz, quiz website, online quiz, politics quiz, programming quiz, general knowledge quiz, gk quiz, history quiz, general knowledge questions" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css" />
<title>Welcome to Best Quiz Questions Website</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
            Login
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
            Sign Up
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="pull-left">
        <img class="img img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" />
        </div>


        <div class="pull-right">
            <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
            <!-- Responsive -->
            <ins class="adsbygoogle responsive"
                 style="display:inline-block"
                 data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                 data-ad-slot="6352682258"></ins>
            <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">

        <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="privacy-policy.php">Privacy policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="sitemap.php">Sitemap</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also, the adsense ad is not showing up on this page, although it is showing on pages that I have not yet started implementing in Bootstrap.

I am sorry for too many question in one question, but they are all much inter-related. Previously I was trying to use the image and the ad between the two navbar without the jumbotron, but in that case, the second navbar would overlay the image. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell from that image, it would help if you installed something like chrome dev tools, but looking at it, my guess is that the image is a transparent PNG, and the there is a large transparent area around the logo, which you cannot see but its acting as margin, take the logo into photoshop and crop it accordingly.

Comment: No. It does not have any large transparent area around it.. Here is the image. [link](http://imgur.com/guqA3XI)

Comment: If thats the case its a floating issue, add this to the jumbotron css;

Overflow: Hidden;

Comment: But that would obviously hide the part of the image that is not fitting in the jumbotron. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Nope, I always thought that. But no it doesn't its very odd actually.

<div class="jumbotron" style="overflow: hidden;>

Comment: If that doesn't work, you're going to need to float the jumbotron div by adding float:left to it, or maybe trying display:block.

Comment: Well, it served the purpose. But will you please explain how did this happened?

Comment: And could you please answer my other two questions?

Comment: So it worked? i'm unsure, I think its just a fault in the css its self, if someone could explain why this happens it would help me out as well! I end up using overflow:hidden all the time now!

Comment: I cant solve the other two I'm afraid but I'd say ditch the jumbotron and try it all without it! Also use some web dev tools like chrome dev tools.